# Labels not responding to changes

Tags: ios, objective-c, properties, uilabel

I have a problem, I have a couple view controllers. One is called `PSACurrentGame`, the other is called `PSAEnterScores`. `PSACurrentGame` is the parent class for `PSAEnterScores`. I'm trying to change labels in `PSACurrentGame` from `PSAEnterScores`. But I already figured that out with the parent class thing. The real problem is that, while I have the correct property linked with the variable the variable's text won't change. I confirmed that the lanbel responds to changes in the `viewDidLoad` method, but it won't respond to it being changed in a child class. Does anyone know why?

Code below:

`PSACurrentGame.h`:

```
@interface PSACurrentGame : UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *R1P1Score;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *R1P1Phase;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *R2P1Score;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *R2P1Phase;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *R3P1Score;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *R3P1Phase;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *ToP1Score;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *ToP1Phase;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *R1P2Score;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *R1P2Phase;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *R2P2Score;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *R2P2Phase;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *R3P2Score;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *R3P2Phase;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *ToP2Score;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *ToP2Phase;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *R1P3Score;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *R1P3Phase;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *R2P3Score;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *R2P3Phase;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *R3P3Score;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *R3P3Phase;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *ToP3Score;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *ToP3Phase;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *R1P4Score;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *R1P4Phase;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *R2P4Score;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *R2P4Phase;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *R3P4Score;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *R3P4Phase;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *ToP4Score;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *ToP4Phase;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *R1P5Score;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *R1P5Phase;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *R2P5Score;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *R2P5Phase;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *R3P5Score;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *R3P5Phase;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *ToP5Score;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *ToP5Phase;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *R1P6Score;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *R1P6Phase;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *R2P6Score;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *R2P6Phase;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *R3P6Score;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *R3P6Phase;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *ToP6Score;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *ToP6Phase;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *player1;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *player2;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *player3;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *player4;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *player5;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *player6;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *R1List2;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *R2List2;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *R3List2;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *ToList2;
- (void) updateScores;


@end
```

`PSACurrentGame.m`:

```
@interface PSACurrentGame ()



@end

@implementation PSACurrentGame

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view
    self.ToP1Score = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,100,50)];
    [self.ToP1Score setTextColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    [self.ToP1Score setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:30]];
    PSAGlobal *global = [PSAGlobal getInstance];

    self.player1.text = global.player1Name;
    self.player2.text = global.player2Name;
    self.player3.text = global.player3Name;
    self.player4.text = global.player4Name;
    self.player5.text = global.player5Name;
    self.player6.text = global.player6Name;

    if ([self.player3.text isEqual: @""]) {
        self.player3.hidden = YES;
        self.R1P3Phase.hidden = YES;
        self.R1P3Score.hidden=YES;
        self.R2P3Phase.hidden = YES;
        self.R2P3Score.hidden=YES;
        self.R3P3Phase.hidden = YES;
        self.R3P3Score.hidden=YES;
        self.ToP3Phase.hidden = YES;
        self.ToP3Score.hidden=YES;
    }

    if ([self.player4.text isEqual: @""]) {
        self.player4.hidden = YES;
        self.R1P4Phase.hidden = YES;
        self.R1P4Score.hidden=YES;
        self.R2P4Phase.hidden = YES;
        self.R2P4Score.hidden=YES;
        self.R3P4Phase.hidden = YES;
        self.R3P4Score.hidden=YES;
        self.ToP4Phase.hidden = YES;
        self.ToP4Score.hidden=YES;
    }
    if ([self.player5.text isEqual: @""]) {
        self.player5.hidden = YES;
        self.R1P5Phase.hidden = YES;
        self.R1P5Score.hidden=YES;
        self.R2P5Phase.hidden = YES;
        self.R2P5Score.hidden=YES;
        self.R3P5Phase.hidden = YES;
        self.R3P5Score.hidden=YES;
        self.ToP5Phase.hidden = YES;
        self.ToP5Score.hidden=YES;
    }

    if ([self.player6.text isEqual: @""]) {
        self.player6.hidden = YES;
        self.R1P6Phase.hidden = YES;
        self.R1P6Score.hidden=YES;
        self.R2P6Phase.hidden = YES;
        self.R2P6Score.hidden=YES;
        self.R3P6Phase.hidden = YES;
        self.R3P6Score.hidden=YES;
        self.ToP6Phase.hidden = YES;
        self.ToP6Score.hidden=YES;
    }

    if ([self.player4.text isEqual: @""] && [self.player5.text isEqual:@""] && [self.player6.text isEqual:@""]) {
        self.R1List2.hidden = YES;
        self.R2List2.hidden = YES;
        self.R3List2.hidden = YES;
        self.ToList2.hidden = YES;
    }


}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

`PSAEnterScores.h`:

```
@interface PSAEnterScores : PSACurrentGame

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *player1Txt;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *player2Txt;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *player3Txt;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *player4Txt;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *player5Txt;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *player6Txt;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *player1Lbl;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *player2Lbl;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *player3Lbl;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *player4Lbl;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *player5Lbl;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *player6Lbl;

@end
```

`PSAEnterScores.m`:

```
@interface PSAEnterScores ()

- (IBAction)ok:(id)sender;

@end

@implementation PSAEnterScores

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    PSAGlobal *global = [PSAGlobal getInstance];
    self.player1Lbl.text = global.player1Name;
    self.player2Lbl.text = global.player2Name;
    self.player3Lbl.text = global.player3Name;
    self.player4Lbl.text = global.player4Name;
    self.player5Lbl.text = global.player5Name;
    self.player6Lbl.text = global.player6Name;

    if ([self.player3Lbl.text isEqual:@""]) {
        self.player3Lbl.hidden = YES;
        self.player3Txt.hidden = YES;
    }

    if ([self.player4Lbl.text isEqual:@""]) {
        self.player4Lbl.hidden = YES;
        self.player4Txt.hidden = YES;
    }

    if ([self.player5Lbl.text isEqual:@""]) {
        self.player5Lbl.hidden = YES;
        self.player5Txt.hidden = YES;
    }

    if ([self.player6Lbl.text isEqual:@""]) {
        self.player6Lbl.hidden = YES;
        self.player6Txt.hidden = YES;
    }



}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;

}

- (IBAction)ok:(id)sender {
    [self.ToP1Score setText:self.player1Txt.text];

    self.R3P1Score.text = self.R2P1Score.text;
    self.R3P1Phase.text = self.R2P1Phase.text;
    self.R3P2Score.text = self.R2P2Score.text;
    self.R3P2Phase.text = self.R2P2Phase.text;
    self.R3P3Score.text = self.R2P3Score.text;
    self.R3P3Phase.text = self.R2P3Phase.text;
    self.R3P4Score.text = self.R2P4Score.text;
    self.R3P4Phase.text = self.R2P4Phase.text;
    self.R3P5Score.text = self.R2P5Score.text;
    self.R3P5Phase.text = self.R2P5Phase.text;
    self.R3P6Score.text = self.R2P6Score.text;
    self.R3P6Phase.text = self.R2P6Phase.text;
    //Round 1 -> Round 2
    self.R2P1Score.text = self.R1P1Score.text;
    self.R2P1Phase.text = self.R1P1Phase.text;
    self.R2P2Score.text = self.R1P2Score.text;
    self.R2P2Phase.text = self.R1P2Phase.text;
    self.R2P3Score.text = self.R1P3Score.text;
    self.R2P3Phase.text = self.R1P3Phase.text;
    self.R2P4Score.text = self.R1P4Score.text;
    self.R2P4Phase.text = self.R1P4Phase.text;
    self.R2P5Score.text = self.R1P5Score.text;
    self.R2P5Phase.text = self.R1P5Phase.text;
    self.R2P6Score.text = self.R1P6Score.text;
    self.R2P6Phase.text = self.R1P6Phase.text;
    //Total -> Round 1
    self.R1P1Score.text = self.ToP1Score.text;
    self.R1P1Phase.text = self.ToP1Phase.text;
    self.R1P2Score.text = self.ToP2Score.text;
    self.R1P2Phase.text = self.ToP2Phase.text;
    self.R1P3Score.text = self.ToP3Score.text;
    self.R1P3Phase.text = self.ToP3Phase.text;
    self.R1P4Score.text = self.ToP4Score.text;
    self.R1P4Phase.text = self.ToP4Phase.text;
    self.R1P5Score.text = self.ToP5Score.text;
    self.R1P5Phase.text = self.ToP5Phase.text;
    self.R1P6Score.text = self.ToP6Score.text;
    self.R1P6Phase.text = self.ToP6Phase.text;
    //Setting Total's score
    //Setting Player 1's Score // This section is where the ToP1Score should be changed, but it isn't!
    NSInteger curScore = [self.ToP1Score.text integerValue];
    NSInteger curPhase = [self.ToP1Phase.text integerValue];
    self.ToP1Score.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", (curScore += [self.player1Txt.text integerValue])];
    if ([self.player1Txt.text integerValue] < 50) {
        self.ToP1Phase.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", (curPhase += 1)];
    }


   }

- (void) updateScores {

}

@end
```

If you need anything more just comment, and I'll add.

EDIT: I changed the text at the top, but I'll put it down here too. The label now responds to changes in its own class, but now in child classes. Do child classes only have read-only permission to access parent class variables?

Comment: To the left of all your IBOutlet properties is a circle.  If that circle has a dot in it the property is linked to something in the view.  If there is no dot the property is not linked.  Make sure the properties you're attempting to set as view elements are linked.

Comment: Also make sure you're not creating multiple copies of the same view controller.  Only one can be displayed at a time, and changes in others will not be visible.

Comment: Beyond that, there's far too many fields there, and far too little info about your specific problem for us to be of much assistance.  You need to give us something to work with.

Comment: @HotLicks The Outlet is linked correctly. My specific problem is that when I try and change a labels value in a different view controller, the label doesn't change. How would you have multiple of the same view controller? I'm using storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have two things you could improve:

1) Use IBOutletCollection instead of creating one for each of your interface controls;

2) Use a shared datasource and get notified when its values changes. Then you can make changes in your controls, inside their own ViewControllers, like that:

```
self.dataStore addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"gameScore" options:0 context:nil];

//...

- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath
                  ofObject:(id)object
                    change:(NSDictionary *)change
                   context:(void *)context {

    if ([keyPath isEqual:@"gameScore"]) {
        //update your IBOutletCollections...
    }
}
```

**Reference**
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/Articles/KVOBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002252-BAJEAIEE

Comment: Thanks, let me work on this. It will take me some time, since I already have a bunch of code written. Just so you know, I'm trying to change one view controller's properties from a different view controller.

Comment: So one question, is it normal for labels not to be changed when you try to change them outside their View Controller? Also does the data store solution work cross platform? So would the observer work in a different class? Also, my classes might not be KVO compliant. I'll have to check that.

Answer (score 0):

I used this example in my application to transfer data between view controllers. So, it may helps: http://iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/54859-sharing-data-between-view-controllers-and-other-objects-link-fixed.html

Comment: I currently have a global variable class, and it's working find. That would work but I need a event to trigger the changing of labels.